# Call requires API level 29 (current min is 21): android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable#setPadding

Tags: android, android-view, android-drawable

Everytime i want to make this view below, i make a drawable resource and apply it to a view.
[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:left="-1dp"
        android:bottom="-1dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke android:color="#d7d7d7" android:width="@dimen/px01" />
            <solid android:color="@color/white" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Now, I'm trying to make a code which applies border line programmatically. 
The border line will be only shown top/right of the line and so on from time to time. 
[image]

So, I decided to use the `GradientDrawable#setPadding()`.

```
fun makeRectangleGradientDrawable(
    left: Int = 0,
    top: Int = 0,
    right: Int = 0,
    bottom: Int = 0,
    shape: Int = GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE,
    strokeWidth: Int = 1,
    strokeColor: Int,
    backgroundColor: Int
): GradientDrawable {
    return GradientDrawable().apply {
        this.setPadding(left, top, right, bottom) // Call requires API level 29 (current min is 21): android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable#setPadding
        this.shape = shape
        setStroke(strokeWidth, strokeColor)
    }
}
```

But my app supports API21(Lollipop) now and i can't use it.
How can i make it by using GradientDrawable()? Or could you tell me a way to make it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the best option would be to wrap your gradient drawable in LayerList drawable and add some insets pixels to the edges.

```
fun makeRectangleGradientDrawable(
    left: Int = 0,
    top: Int = 0,
    right: Int = 0,
    bottom: Int = 0,
    shape: Int = GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE,
    strokeWidth: Int = 1,
    strokeColor: Int,
    backgroundColor: Int
): Drawable {
    val border = GradientDrawable()
    border.setStroke(1, strokeColor)
    border.shape = GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE
    val layers = arrayOf<Drawable>(border)
    val layerDrawable = LayerDrawable(layers)
    layerDrawable.setLayerInset(0, left, top, right, bottom)
    return layerDrawable
}
```

Comment: a perfect workaround! thanks a lot! in this case, for instance, if i want to remove the left line, then i can set the `setLayerInset()` like this. 
`setLayerInsetn(0, -strokeWidth, top, right, bottom)`.